# My JS function does not return the value I want

Tags: javascript

Why does the value of `(a)` not change, despite this function:

```js
var a = 0;

function myFunction() {
  a = 1;
}

if (a === 1) {
  alert(a);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">1</button>
```

Comment: Your function does not contain code that reports the value of `a`. What is the intended behaviour?

Comment: I want the button to update the variable (a) to a value of 1 
it doesn't have to be a function so that the value a is rewritten but unfortunately i don't know any other possibility

Comment: Calling a function is the right decision. But the variable a **is** rewritten. How did you come to the conclusion it isn't?

Comment: when i test it with an alert (a) is still displayed as 0 xd

Comment: Please update your question so we can see that happening in the runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0):

your button calls the myFunction but you if statement is outside of the function

```js
let a = 0;
       function myFunction(myValue) {
        a = parseInt(myValue) ;

        if (a === 1) { 
            alert(a);
            }
        else {
            alert("a isn't = 1, it is = " + a)
        }
       }
```

```html
<input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>
    
    <button onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('a').value)">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are implementing the condition outside your `function()`.That means you are not getting the condition while button `click`. So you need to place the condition inside the `function()`.

```js
var a = 0;
function myFunction() {
 a = 1;
 if(a === 1){
  alert(a)}
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">1</button>
```

Or you can make another function and call it inside `myFunction`

```js
var a = 0;
function myFunction() {
 a = 1;
 check()
}
function check(){
  if(a === 1){
  alert(a) }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">1</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, if I understood correctly, the variable (a) now stays inside the function and cannot be used outside the function unless you add a function inside the function again

what would i have to do to check it outside the function (if it is possible)

Answer (score 0):

Everyone here answered your question with a normal approach, I thought to put a different method to achieve this using an observable object which is created using a proxy.

**Use this if you wish to have multiple state-changing functions.**

```
var a,b,c, ...;
function set_a() {a = 1}
function set_b() {b = 0}
function set_c() {c = 4}
...
```

**Otherwise, it is unnecessary to create such an observer to capture a single variable change.**

```
// creating an observable object using a proxy.
function useState(stateCallback) {
  const state = {}
  return new Proxy(state, {
    get(target, key, value) {
      return Reflect.get(target, key, value)
    },
    set(target, key, value) {
      const prev = {...target};
      Reflect.set(target, key, value)
      stateCallback({prev, current: state})
      return true;
    }
  })

}


const state = useState(callback)
state.a = 0;


function myfunction() {
  state.a = 1;
}

function callback({prev, current}) {
  // when the state object changes this callback will be called.
  console.log(`prev object is ${prev} and it changes to ${current}`)

 if(current.a === 1) alert('a is ', a)
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, this seems like extreme overkill to update and alert/log the new value of a single variable.

Comment: yeah, I know. but this can be used to capture multiple state changes if OP wants to extend his/her program.